# what is the actual difference between reference variable and object

Tags: c#, .net, class, object

I have been reading a lot and now i really confused. Consider an ordinary instantiation:

```
Sampleclass  instance1  = new Sampleclass();
```

After reading a lot I came to know that `instance1` is a reference variable stored in a stack which contains the memory address of the object's data which is stored in heap.

If this is correct then where is object? `instance1` is also a object. Sometimes I have seen only declaration like `new Sampleclass()`. Is that sufficient for object instantiation?

Comment: `new SampleClass()` is an initialization of a new object that is not being referenced by a variable.

Comment: What do you mean by "where is object?" The only object is the Sampleclass you created and as you said, it is in the heap; with instance1 holding a memory address to the location of the object.

Comment: @Cemafor then what is object here ?instance1 also a object?

Comment: @peter: I generally think of instance1 as the object. In reality, instance1 is just a pointer to a memory address that happens to contain a Sampleclass, but C#/.NET hides that fact fairly well. If you want to seperate the idea of instance1 from the actuall SampleClass, I would consider the Sampleclass as an object, but the instance1 is just a pointer, not an actual object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`instance1` is a variable.

Because its type is a reference type, it is a reference to an object instance that lives on the heap.

`new SampleClass()` is a constructor call that creates a new object on the heap and returns a reference to it.

Comment: so object is something that lives in heap, doesn't have any name, but only members initialized by constructor and referenced by instance1 rite? Previously what i thought was object(instance) is instance1.SO after your definition it is reference variable that points to an instance

Answer (score 1):

instance1 contains the copy of the reference which points to the memory where new objet Sampleclass() is created. What's confusing is instance1 is mere a copy of a reference, which is different from reference ref (C# Reference), which might confuse you as it confused me.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `new Sampleclass()` creates an object. It also has a *value* which is a pointer to that object. You can do something with this pointer such as store it in a variable (e.g. `Sampleclass  instance1  = new Sampleclass();`  ) or you can ignore it.

Why create something and ignore it? Because its constructor might have beneficial side effects for example.

Comment: Side effects in constructors are hardly ever "beneficial" :)

Comment: @dzendras OK. So why _would_ you have `new Sampleclass();` alone in code? (Or was it mainly humor?)

Comment: @ispiro Probably the most common example that I've seen is a main class that does all of the entire program's work in it's constructor so that `Main` is doing nothing but constructing an instance of that.

Comment: @ispiro: I just wanted to say that (in general) constructors shouldn't do more than veryfing the arguments and doing simple assigments to fields/properties. All behaviour should be encapsulated in methods. It's easy to grasp once you apply Single Responsiblity Principle to a method (let's assume constructor is a special method). One method should do only one thing. Constructor is supposed to create an object. All other actions violate the rule. Please mind that as with everything (especially software design) common sense is the first principle to follow.

Comment: @spiro: Applying SPR to methods is very useful and makes the code better. Imagine you have to test a method using unit tests. It's much easier to write (and understand after some time) what a method does and what's the impact of arguments passed in test on SUT.

Answer (score 0):

1) Sampleclass (Type)  > Container type

2) instance1 (Identifier)  > user-friendly name of reference (01010101010) of data which is stored in memory (heap) and "instance1" itself stored in the stack with reference (01010101010)

3) = (operator)  > to asign left side  value to right side

4) new (keyword) > Purchase a new space to stored data

5) Sampleclass();  (Constructor )  > make a copy of Type "Sampleclass" and stored in newly purchased space (this is actually an object or instance) and this accessed by its name  "instance1" because "instance1" know the actual location of stored data in heap memory.