# C# is it a reference?

Tags: c#

At the top of the class, in the field members, what is the name for Teacher teacher;

I know this allows us access to the Teacher class; its Properties and methods. I'd like to know if its called a reference or an instance of a class so I can read up a bit more to clarify my understanding of it.

Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P3_O_O_P
{
    public class Classroom
    {
        private int roomNo;
        private string className;
        Teacher teacher;
        public List<Student> stuList = new List<Student>();

        public Classroom(int newRoomNo, string newRoomName)
        {
            roomNo = newRoomNo;
            className = newRoomName;
        }

        public Classroom()
        {
        }

        public void addStudent(string studentName, int studentID)
        {
            stuList.Add(new Student(studentName, studentID));
        }

        public void addTeacher(string teacherName, int teacherID)
        {
            teacher = new Teacher(teacherName, teacherID);

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            Console.WriteLine("\nTeacher name: " + teacherName + "\nTeacher ID: " + teacherID + "\nSystem updated!\n");
        }

        public void viewClass()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stuList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stuList[i].toString());
            }
            if (teacher != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(teacher.toString());
            }
        }

        public void removeTeacher()
        {
            teacher = null;
        }

        public string ClassName
        {
            get
            {
                return className;
            }
            set
            {
                className = value;
            }
        }

        public int ClassNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return roomNo;
            }
            set
            {
                roomNo = value;
            }
        }

        public void removeStudent(int id)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < stuList.Count(); i++)
            {
                int ID = stuList[i].ID;
                if (id == ID)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nStudent name: {0}\nStudent number: {1}\n\nStudent removed from classroom\n\nSystem updated!\n\n", stuList[i].Name, stuList[i].ID);

                    stuList.RemoveAt(i);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **Yes**.  it is a reference to instance of the class.

Comment: The definition of it within the class is a [Field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Comment: Syntactically it is a field. It is implemented as a reference to an instance.

Comment: You need to read about those topic, to clarify and understand the diference and know when it's a reference o a object http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341828/what-is-the-actual-difference-between-reference-variable-and-object

Comment: I recommend reading [C# Concepts: Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

`Teacher` is the name of the class. `teacher` is a reference to an instance of the teacher class.

Another way of thinking about it: `teacher` is a variable of type `Teacher`.

Comment: So, if I get this right. It's like saying:

int i;

int being what Teacher is and i being what teacher is, right?

Comment: @mason: Yes, and to be more specific, `teacher` is a _member_ variable of type `Teacher`.

Comment: @Rayne Blackham: Yes, with the added detail that `teacher` is a _reference_ type, while `i` is a _value_ type. See [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).

Comment: You mean Teacher is the reference type and i is the value type, yeah? My mistake, teacher, the variable is the reference.

Comment: @RayneBlackham You're confusing yourself with all this reference vs value. You really don't need to know that. I specifically steered away from mentioning that in my answer so that it would be easy for you to understand. But if you really want to know about reference vs value, look at the comment Sriram left on your question.

Comment: I just made a very quick program that pretty much cleared the whole thing up as I was making it.

Teacher is the object.
teacher is the reference to that object, lets say, it contains the directions to the object.

Hence why, when adding to a list, you instantiate a new object each time and during each tick, the same member variable holds the directions to each object added to that list.

Comment: @RayneBlackham Teacher is the type of object. teacher is an instance of the Teacher type.

Comment: Basically, in a nutshell; I figure the following to be true;

Teacher teacher = new teacher();

Teacher is the object type.

teacher is the reference or instance of that particular/specific object.

the "new" keyword creates a block of memory for that particular object and the reference to that object which allows it to find it.

The constructor is then called which places the data input into that created/allocated memory space.

Answer (score 1):

It creates a `teacher` which is `Teacher` type. By creating an object we can access to its public members. We are also say that we create an instance to a class.

Comment: In fact, `Teacher teacher` only *declares* a variable which can hold a reference to an instance of `Teacher`.  An actual instance of `Teacher` is not created until `teacher = new Teacher(teacherName, teacherID);` where `teacher` then contains a valid reference to the newly created instance.

Comment: Yes of course. I assume that OP will create that object soon

Answer (score 1):

`teacher` is a member variable of type `Teacher` and it is a *reference* type (not a *value* type). Once the `teacher` is instantiated, via the `addTeacher()` method, it will refer to a specific instance of the `Teacher` class.